# How to display ONLY "Add new item"?

Tags: list-item

I see lots of people on Teh Interwebs trying to block the "Add new item" line that comes up on SharePoint lists, but I want to do the inverse -- I want to have ONLY the "Add new item" line, green '+' and all, pointing to a page with a form connected to a data source (Access).  Actually, I want 3 of them, each pointing to a different form.  There's an example of this that I'm looking at (intranet only, sorry), and from looking at the page source it looks like it was done directly in SharePoint, with no custom code.  (The site author is unavailable.)  I thought about creating a list and removing everything but the "Add new item", but I tried and it doesn't seem possible, in SP or SP Designer.  Any ideas?

Comment: Mike, you have separate pages for the forms? Why don't you just create links, may be a Links list

Answer (score 0):

Just Find Webpart Id Replace WebPartWPQ2 using F12 you can find webpart id then you place this code in current page

#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 .ms-listviewtable{

display: none;

}

Comment: is it help you, if any difficult reply for this comment